# scmmanager - how can I modify the name of a namespace?

Tags: namespaces, scmmanager

In scm Manager I would like to change the name of a namespace that contains svn code repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The namespaces in SCM-Manager are handled by the "Namespace Strategy" which can be set in the global settings. This strategy is used, when a new repository is created. To set your own namespaces, you can set this to "Custom". To change the name and the namespace of a repository, just open the repository settings and select "Rename Repository" in the lower part (the namespace can only be changed, if the namespace strategy is set to "Custom").

It is not possible to "rename" a namespace as a whole, so this must be done for each repository individually.